EF Core ManyToMany Join Table with same Model relationship, Cascade Delete Behaviour Issue
Join table with two of the same Entities holds the relationship of those entities. The problem is the foreign key constraint preventing the cascade delete behaviour, which is what is required by my application logic.
I have an Employee Entity, and a ManagedBy join table that I want to represent the managerial relationship between Employees. The ManagedBy consists of ManagerId and Subordinate (both Employees) with its key being the composite of these two. The issue lies in the OnDelete behavior where I want to remove any associated ManagedBy entry when removing the Employee regardless of whether it was a Manager or Subordinate.
When scaffolding I cannot use following cascading delete behavior:
modelBuilder.Entity<ManagedBy>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(x => new {x.ManagerId, x.SubordinateId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<ManagedBy>()
            .HasOne(em => em.Manager)
            .WithMany(e => e.MBManagers)
            .HasForeignKey(em => em.ManagerId);
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


    modelBuilder.Entity<ManagedBy>()
            .HasOne(em => em.Subordinate)
            .WithMany(e => e.MBSubordinates)
            .HasForeignKey(em => em.SubordinateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});

I get this error when calling Update-Database:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ManagedBys_AspNetUsers_SubordinateId' on table 'ManagedBys' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

When using suggested No Action delete behavior on subordinate, I can delete the Manager and the related ManageBy entries are also deleted, but not the Subordinate:
modelBuilder.Entity<ManagedBy>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(x => new {x.ManagerId, x.SubordinateId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<ManagedBy>()
            .HasOne(em => em.Manager)
            .WithMany(e => e.MBManagers)
            .HasForeignKey(em => em.ManagerId);
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);


    modelBuilder.Entity<ManagedBy>()
            .HasOne(em => em.Subordinate)
            .WithMany(e => e.MBSubordinates)
            .HasForeignKey(em => em.SubordinateId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
});

As I understand, this is to prevent the multiple cascade paths in cases where two Employees have ManagedBy entries in which they are both manager and subordinate to each other, or am I mistaken? I'm sure I'm missing something.
How do I ensure that all ManageBy entries are deleted when related Employee is deleted regardless of whether he is manager or subordinate?

I have removed the  tag since this isn't directly related to the SQL language. Consider a  tag instead.

"...or am I mistaken? I'm sure I'm missing something." You miss nothing, it is exactly as you wrote it. And is a famous SqlServer database limitation. It's been asked million of times (just search for "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"). Shortly, SqlServer won't allow you to have cascade delete for one of the FKs forming the "multiple cascade path" (other databases do), so the question goes there. No good solution, use one of the workarounds.

To cascade delete entries from a join table that links two instances of the same entity without running into the "multiple cascade paths" issue you could try one of the below suggestions:
1)Manual Deletion in the Application Logic
2)Handle deletions at the database level but without the cascade issue, you might need to split the relationships into two separate join tables or use triggers. for that you have to create two separate join tables: one for Managers and one for Subordinates.
3)Implement soft deletes can also help manage such relationships. Instead of deleting records, mark them as deleted.
You can choose the approach based on your application. below is explanation of the Manual Deletion solution:
Rather than relying entirely on database constraints, manually delete the related entries in the ManagedBy table before deleting the employee. This way, you entirely avoid the potential issues with multiple cascade paths.
Write a function in your application code that deletes `ManagedBy` entries related to the employee before deleting the employee itself.


public async Task DeleteEmployeeAsync(int employeeId)
   {
       using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
       {
           var managedByEntries = context.ManagedBy
               .Where(mb => mb.ManagerId == employeeId || mb.SubordinateId == employeeId);

           context.ManagedBy.RemoveRange(managedByEntries);

           var employee = await context.Employees.FindAsync(employeeId);
           context.Employees.Remove(employee);

           await context.SaveChangesAsync();
       }
   }

